How to change BorderThickness and BorderBrush on Entry in MAUI
I know there are some Q/A on this topic but I couldnt find a solution for this case.
I am trying to style the Entry control for Windows. I want to change the default BorderThickness and BorderBrush in normal, PointerOver and Focused visual states for Light and Dark themes.
Following some answers from stack overflow and the documentation itself I managed to access the properties but not for all cases needed, for example:
This would be my preffered choice for clarity, but it only works for Normal Visual state, since I can't access the VisualStates. GetVisualStateGroups() returns an empty collection, so I couldnt test the rest of the code.
In MauiProgram CreateMauiApp() before  return builder.Build();:
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Entry), (handler, view) =>
{
#if WINDOWS
    var borderThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1);
    var borderBrush = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 175, 175, 175));
    var pointerOverBorderBrush = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 143, 143, 143));

    Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox windowsNativeView = handler.PlatformView;
    windowsNativeView.BorderThickness = borderThickness;
    windowsNativeView.BorderBrush = borderBrush;

    var visualStateGroups = Microsoft.UI.Xaml.VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(windowsNativeView);

    //focused
    var focusedAnimationObjects = visualStateGroups
        .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == "Focused")?
        .States.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Focused")?
        .Storyboard?.Children.OfType<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>();

    var borderThicknessAnimation = focusedAnimationObjects?
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType().GetProperty("TargetProperty")?.GetValue(a)?.ToString() == "(UIElement.BorderThickness)");

    if (borderThicknessAnimation != null)
    {
        borderThicknessAnimation.KeyFrames.Clear();
        borderThicknessAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame()
        {
            KeyTime = TimeSpan.Zero,
            Value = borderThickness
        });
    }

    var borderBrushAnimation = focusedAnimationObjects?
        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType().GetProperty("TargetProperty")?.GetValue(a)?.ToString() == "(UIElement.BorderBrush)");

    if (borderBrushAnimation != null)
    {
        borderBrushAnimation.KeyFrames.Clear();
        borderBrushAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame()
        {
            KeyTime = TimeSpan.Zero,
            Value = borderBrush
        });
    }

    //pointerover
    var pointerOverBorderBrushAnimation = visualStateGroups
        .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == "PointerOver")?
        .States.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "PointerOver")?
        .Storyboard?.Children.OfType<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>()?
        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType().GetProperty("TargetProperty")?.GetValue(a)?.ToString() == "(UIElement.BorderBrush)");

    if (pointerOverBorderBrushAnimation != null)
    {
        pointerOverBorderBrushAnimation.KeyFrames.Clear();
        pointerOverBorderBrushAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame()
        {
            KeyTime = TimeSpan.Zero,
            Value = pointerOverBorderBrush
        });
    }
#endif
});

I also tried simpler approaches such as subscribing to the GettingFocus, GotFocus, LosingFocus, LostFocus, FocusEngaged, FocusDisengaged, FocusChanged, PointerEntered and PointerExited of the native view (TextBox) and changing the BorderThickness and BorderBrush but it didnt make a difference.
For example changing the above to the following doesnt change the Focused visual state:
var borderThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1);
var borderBrush = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 175, 175, 175));
var pointerOverBorderBrush = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 143, 143, 143));

Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox windowsNativeView = handler.PlatformView;
windowsNativeView.BorderThickness = borderThickness;
windowsNativeView.BorderBrush = borderBrush;

windowsNativeView.GotFocus += (s, e) =>
{
    windowsNativeView.BorderThickness = borderThickness;
    windowsNativeView.BorderBrush = borderBrush;
};

PS: By changing the focused visual state in this case I just mean to remove the thick blue underline, the above code should retain the same style wile focused and unfocused.

Then, a less prefered aproach, removing the code above and modifying the Platforms/Windows/App.xaml to include:
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBorderBrush" Color="#bbb"/>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0,0,0,1</Thickness>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="#999"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBorderBrushFocused" Color="#bbb"/>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0,0,0,1</Thickness>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>

Works for one theme I tried to include as ThemeDictionaries with Light and Dark keys, I tried a few other things to change the theme on the WinUI but at this point I lost track of all attempts.
In conclusion, for the first example, can we access and change the border properties of the native view on the different visual states? And what I believe should be the simpler answer, how can I change the Theme on the WinUI portion of the code? particularly for this properties that seem like black magic (I believe its just overriding the system id`s for those properties but still)

References:
SO answer that laid the ground work
.Net Maui Handlers Documentation
Microsoft Style library where I got the "magic" xaml keys
Miscelaneous link, great SO answer but its a creating a whole new control with fullyfledged handlers and all that, my question is in hope to avoid all that, I have 1 Entry in my app.

Per your references and the basis of your code, a workaround is currently required to create a borderless Entry. Go back to that version, then wrap it in a Border component that you can customize.

You can refer to this.

thanks, if not mistaken border does not allow "thickness" but I currently am using the "no border" workaround with a BoxView as underline but that adds a layout and a control. Its seriously not possible to change WinUI color properties based on MAUI AppTheme? I couldnt reach that far but I thought was just me that never used platform specific code.
